# AngularJS : selected option not working in <select><option> WITHOUT ngModel

Tags: angular, combobox, default-value

My problem is when i put a variable in the value attribute of my <option> the selected attibute do not work longer and nothing is showed by default in my combobox

```
<select class="form-control" id="status" formControlName="status">
   <option value="" selected>-- Placeholder --</option>
   <option value="{{variable1}}">Text 1</option>
   <option value="{{variable2}}">Text 2</option>
   <option value="{{variable3}}">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

In the las three <options> if value="" all works but when i put a variable or something else inside nothing is default showed i already tried with [selected]="true", with selected="false" on these three <option>. I know we can't use ngModel with it but i haven't this attribute

Anyone know how to solve this and preselect the first <option> on my combobox ?

Comment: Assuming that your FormGroup is `form`, you can preselect in Typescript like this `this.form.get('status').setValue(this.variable1);` or in the initialization `this.form = this.fb.group({ status: [this.variable1] });`

Comment: Yes but it's not my request i just want '-- Placeholder --' written in the combobox at the page loading. It's not a real value because this option is disabled it's just a placeholder text ^^

Answer (score 4):

It's working if value in template is set to `null`. Even without the `selected` attribute.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select class="form-control" id="status" formControlName="status">
    <option [value]="null" selected>-- Placeholder --</option>
    <option [value]="variable1">Text 1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

```js
this.form = fb.group({
  status: []
});
```

Comment: It was just that >< ! Thank you !